Использование тегов в html
Для блока стоит использовать семантику списка с вложенными пунктами списка. В каждом пункте списка — ссылка, а внутри ссылки — элемент карточки (рекомендуем использовать тег <article>).
от ревьюера пришел такой комментарий, не понял в чем заключается его посыл, подскажите пожалуйста

Подозреваю что у вас диватоз, а ревьюер предлагает использовать списки (ul/li).

Он наверное имел ввиду такой вывод - TitleDescription ну и получается li можно размножить в зависимости от количества элементов списка. Хотя не знаю зачем именно такой вывод, когда article тут не нужен по идее

А так не стесняйтесь уточнять у работодателя, если не понимаете. Они умничают много описывая задачи заумными словами. А ты понимай как хочешь.

Все так как Вы и сказали, спасибо!)

Я вижу это так, что лучше в верстке использовать специальные теги, например не писать <div class="article"></div>, а сделать <article></article> итд


ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.card {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="https://metanit.com/web/html5/2.5.php">
      <article class="card">
        <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/jyfwJ5mF.png" alt="Image 1">
      </article>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://metanit.com/web/html5/4.1.php">
      <article class="card">
        <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/O9gYe8b1.png" alt="Image 2">
      </article>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>



